# Separability of Extended Real Numbers with Metric $d_0(x,y) = |\tan^{-1}(x) -\tan^{-1}(y)|$

Tags: real-analysis

In the analysis of large-scale computer simulation outputs, I am concerned with trying to prove convergence in probability to 0 for a sequence of random variables $\{ \mathcal{Q}_n : n \geq 1 \}$  that can take the values $\pm\infty$ with nonzero probability but $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \Pr\{ |\mathcal{Q}_n |= \infty \} = 0$.  This requires establishing weak convergence on the extended real numbers $\mathbb{R}^* = [-\infty,\infty]$ equipped with the metric $d_0(x,y) = |\tan^{-1}(x) - \tan^{-1}(y)$|.  To apply standard results on convergence of probability measures on a metric space, it is necessary to know that the metric space is separable.  So the questions is this: is the metric space $(\mathbb{R}^*,d_0)$ separable?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.  You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

Answer (score 2):

The formula $p = \tan^{-1}(x)$ exhibits a homeomorphism between $X=\mathbb R^*$ and $Y=[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, where $\mathbb R^*$ is equipped with the metric $d_0$ and $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ is equipped with the metric $d(p,q)=|p-q|$.

Separability of a metric space is the statement that the metric topology has a countable basis, and therefore separability is invariant under any homeomorphism between metric spaces: if $f : X \to Y$ is a homeomorphism of metric spaces and if $\mathcal B$ is a countable basis of $Y$ then $\{f^{-1}(B) \mid B \in \mathcal B\}$ is a countable basis of $X$.

The space $[\pi/2,\pi/2]$, like any subspace $Y \subset \mathbb R$, is indeed separable: the set of intersections $Y \cap (a,b)$ such that $a<b$ and $a,b \in \mathbb Q$ forms a countable basis of $Y$.

Therefore, $\mathbb R^*$ is also separable.